# Taking Screenshot of Webview in above api 21

Tags: android, webview, screenshot

I am trying screenshot of webview in above Api 21 and it only capture content from webview that is visible on screen, other part is also getting captured but without any content. Means it shows white space.

I am using below code for taking screenshot.

```
public static String getScreenShotOf(View view, Context context) {
    try {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return storeImage(context, bitmap);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        UtillsG.showToast("Error while taking screenshot.", context, false);
    }

    return null;
}
```

This things works perfectly in LOLLIPOP or below versions. 
See screenshot of kitkat and marshmallow devices.

Can anybody help me out for this?

Any support will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use root layout as webview and try with below code.

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {

View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(R.id.PP_Ll);
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
return rootView.getDrawingCache();
```

}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File newDir = new File(root + "/Folder");
newDir.mkdirs();
Random gen = new Random();
int n = 10000;
n = gen.nextInt(n);
String fotoname = "Photo-" + n + ".jpg";
File file = new File(newDir, fotoname);
if (file.exists())
    file.delete();
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Saved in folder: 'Folder'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
}

Comment: @SuhebRafique what is `PP_Ll` which you passed in `findViewById()` in second line? 

I tried to put id of my webView but it just take screenshot of whatever is visible on webView.

Comment: PP_Ll is the id of root layout in which your webview is present